# Where can I find some guidelines on how to program a merged mining transaction?

Tags: transactions, protocol, namecoin, merged-mining

In [answer to question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/275/323) ["How does merged mining work?"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/273/323), we can read that in order to merged mine, we need to create a Bitcoin transaction containing a Namecoin block hash and put it on the tip of the merkle tree. Where can one find some guidelines or specification on how to create such a transaction?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at the [merged mining spec](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Merged_mining_specification) at the bitcoin wiki.

When I was writing my merged mining implementation I also looked at the source code of namecoind, bitcoind and [merged-mine-proxy](https://github.com/vinced/namecoin/blob/master/contrib/merged-mine-proxy).

As far as I know there is still no easier documentation on how to implement merged mining, so you will likely be looking through existing source code a lot to figure out the details. The merged mining spec was a big help for me though, even if it is a bit slim.