# How to lower difficulty on blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, difficulty

I created a coin (hexco.in)

The problem now is, sometimes some user create pools and use rented mining rigs to mine on my coin. But after a while they stop and my blockchain stucks at a certain block.

My question now is, how can I solve this problem? I only have a homserver and a raspi2 running as mining service 24/7 for my coin and a seednode running 24/7.

Comment: Is there a specific use case which your blockchain addresses?

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: Did you create your alt-chain to solve a specific problem?

Comment: no not that really. I just want to test the blockchain tech and maybe it will be a good tech for a future project :)

Answer (score 1):

## How to lower difficulty on blockchain?

> The problem now is, sometimes some user create pools and use rented mining rigs to mine on my coin. But after a while they stop and my blockchain stucks at a certain block.

You could include in your expected difficulty calculation a factor of time, where say, for example, every 10 minutes since expected next block time (supposing you have a ten minute average block time) the expected difficulty is lowered by a factor, say divided by 2.

The problem with this method is that it may allow cheating unless you also carefully control network time. If it is not carefully managed then a cheat could submit a block with a future time and a lower difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a permanent solution, but you could try organising a fork in which you manually raise the target value. I doubt that this will protect your alt-chain for long though.

You may find a longer term solution with [merged mining](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/273/how-does-merged-mining-work).

Comment: But I could mine with my home pc's for a longer time and it will generate the block after a while? lets say the network h/s drops from 15 mh/s to about 15 kh/s.

Comment: It won't really matter how you raise the target value, because it is likely you'll encounter the same problem again in the future. Implementing a merged mining solution could prevent this from occurring again.