# Which merged mining method is preferable? What is the latest specification/practice?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, bip, namecoin, merged-mining, rootstock

If I'm right, there are at least [two methods](https://blog.bitmex.com/the-growth-of-bitcoin-merge-mining/) for miners to [include a reference hash to a merge mined block in the coinbase transaction](https://zeroknowledgedefi.com/2022/04/29/merge-mining-and-auxiliary-proof-of-work/#merge_sec4):

1. Commitment hash in an `OP_RETURN` out put in the coinbase transaction (a la RSK)
2. Commitment hash in the input script sig of the coinbase transaction (a la Namecoin)

**A. Which one is preferable from a whole system point of view, and from the point of view of an individual miner**?

There is also a [specification](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Merged_mining_specification#Merged_mining_coinbase) for merklising [multiple merge mined coins into one hash](https://zeroknowledgedefi.com/2022/04/29/merge-mining-and-auxiliary-proof-of-work/#merge_sec5). It has the following note:

> NOTE: This standard is used by Namecoin, but new merged mining data
> should likely propose a new BIP to supercede it with something based
> on p2pool's merged mining.

**B. What is the latest specification, or widely accepted practice, for merged mining?**

**C. Are there any obvious improvements/fixes new merge mined systems could add?**

Finally,

**D. are there any other methods used for merged mining?**

See also:

[BIP301 (draft) Blind merge mining proposal](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0301.mediawiki)

[How does merged mining work?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/273/how-does-merged-mining-work?rq=1)